# Changing color in wordpress theme element

Tags: css, wordpress

We have a website here: http://musegroupreno.com/

It is using the Zerif Pro Theme.

I have been able to change all the colors except for the ones in the Muse With Us section. They are the 4 colored circles with the number 100 inside of them. I have tried using firebug to find where the CSS code is to change this and have tried taking a color sample from them and changing any of those colors in the CSS file to the color we want. This worked for other sections on the site but not here. Can anyone tell me where the code is to change these colors?

Comment: @tenderloin I guess he wants the circles with 100 in `Muse with us` section.

Comment: @ManojKumar I think I need my morning coffee...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS is generated by a plugin called [Knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) which creates the canvas element and is not visible in developer tools CSS panel.

Go to this file: http://musegroupreno.com/wp-content/themes/zerif-pro/js/jquery.knob.min.js in your file server and edit the `fgcolor` values for each skill.

```
jQuery(".skill1").knob({
    'max':100,
    'width': 64,
    'readOnly':true,
    'inputColor':' #FFFFFF ',
    'bgColor':' #222222 ',
    'fgColor':' #e96656 ' /* Change this */
});
```

Comment: Welcome, Matt! Glad that helped :)